# Read in multiple csv files and update columns

Tags: r, loops

I want to ask whether is there any to work efficiently to handle these things.

(1) Load data efficiently

Since the file name was different from the one I want to assign it in the environment, I did this 72 times.

```
P02 <- read.csv("P02_1.csv")
P03 <- read.csv("P03_1.csv")
P04 <- read.csv("P04_1.csv")
P06 <- read.csv("P06_1.csv")
P11 <- read.csv("P11_1.csv")
P12 <- read.csv("P12_1.csv")
P13 <- read.csv("P13_1.csv")
P14 <- read.csv("P14_1.csv")
P15 <- read.csv("P15_1.csv")
```

... But think that there are tons of participants...

(2) Change the time format efficiently

To change the time format, I tried this with a similar approach.

```
P02$Time <- as.POSIXct(P02$Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")                      
P03$Time <- as.POSIXct(P03$Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")                      
P04$Time <- as.POSIXct(P04$Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")                      
P06$Time <- as.POSIXct(P06$Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")                      
P11$Time <- as.POSIXct(P11$Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")                      
P12$Time <- as.POSIXct(P12$Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")                      
P13$Time <- as.POSIXct(P13$Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")                      
P14$Time <- as.POSIXct(P14$Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")                      
P15$Time <- as.POSIXct(P15$Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

... Again, 72 times.

Is there any way to do all these things efficiently?
Had a mind to use "for loop" AND "assign" function, but didn't know how to.

Comment: Do you want to read in all the csv files of that directory?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with a `for` loop and the `assign` function, but I think that a more elegant solution is to store your data frames in a list. Assuming all your csv files are in the same directory, you can iterate through the input files, read them, transform and save the results to a list. Here's an example:

```
directory <- "/path/to/your/data"
files <- list.files(directory)
data_frames <- vector("list", length(files))
for (i in seq_along(files)) {
    df <- read.csv(file.path(directory, files[i]))
    df$Time <- as.POSIXct(df$Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    data_frames[[i]] <- df
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read in all the csv files in the working directory you can use `list.files` to get their names and then read them all in one go. This will create a list of data frames, which is much better than to have 72 objects around the workspace.

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = "csv")
P_list <- lapply(filenames, read.csv)
names(P_list) <- sub("(^P[[:digit:]]{2}).*", "\\1", x)
```

Now you can, once again, use `lapply` to do the transformation you want.

```
P_list <- lapply(P_list, function(x){
        x$Time <- as.POSIXct(x$Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        x
})
```

(Untested, since there's no real data.)

Comment: you should add `path/to/files` in `list.files`

Comment: @CPak I thought of that but the OP is reading from the current directory. The default is `path = "."`. Given the OP's code, there's no reason to change this.